# Expected shortfall

Tags: risk-assessment

I have some diffculties with the following question; Prove that $ES_{\alpha}(L) = \frac{1}{1- \alpha}inf_{c \in {R}}\{E[(L-c)^{+}] + (1-\alpha)c\}$

Hint use

$ES_{\alpha}(L) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}E\big[I_{\{F^{-1}(\alpha) \leq L\}} L\big]$

and assume that

$f(c) = E[(L-c)^{+}] + (1 - \alpha)c$

is a differentiable function

Comment: What have you tried? See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and welcome to MSE! Include **your work** into the post to avoid downvotes and prevent  closing and explain what exactly you have difficulties with so the community members can help you.

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\inf$ using `\inf`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.